# How to use multiple i18n ymls in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use multiple en.yml(and others) for multiple client

for instance,

if the client is boogle, i want to load en_boogle.yml words

en_boogle.yml

```
en:
  title: boogle
```

if it is yumhoo, i want to load en_yumhoo.yml words

en_yumhoo.yml

```
en:
  title: yumhoo
```

Can i configure this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
 en:
     boogle:
       title: Hello Boogle
       ...other boogle stuff
    yumhoo:
       title: Hello Yumhoo
       ...other yumhoo stuff
```

Comment: I dont want to modify the WHOLE existing <%= t(some.path)%>. and also there will be bunch of if statement in every code. <%= t(boogle.some.path)%> if ENV['Client'] == boogle else blah blah